# How to automatically check and record DSL connectivity?

Tags: networking, internet

I suffer from frequent (daily) internet connection losses. When I have a connection, the DSL speed is what my contract says it should be. I want to create a record of these losses. The Bundesntzagentur provides a tool for these situations - [Breitbandmessung](https://www.breitbandmessung.de/desktop-app) - however this requires me to manually initiate every measurement. I don't want to babysit the process. AFAICT the breitbandmessung software has no command line interface.

My first idea is to `ping -i 300 google.com` and pipe the output into a textfile, however so far I don't know how to add a date and time. Also there may be a tool specifically for this purpose, which I could trigger via a cron job or so. Or better command line fu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a background batch, using `cron` with a little script can do what you want.

Typically

```
#! /bin/sh

exec >> /var/log/ping.log
date
ping -c1 google.com |grep transmitted
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a `bash` script that monitors for "network DOWN", then does a user-specified "thing".

You're welcome to adapt it for your need.

`https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic`